# Reference request: Control systems and state space from an only differential equation point of view?

Tags: reference-request

I'm new to this "*forum*", I'm studying control engineering...

While studying this area, one of our lecturers told us that a lot of information is lost when one treats control only from a transfer function point of view.

So what I want to know is, if there are references that manages control from only differential equations or similar and explains **basic and completely how to treat controllers from this point of view**, could you please point me to some of them.

Note: Being even more specific how do you design controllers if you couldn't use the Laplace transform.

Thanks in advance.